# Swapping a website according to weekday?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cron, html

So, I have a bit of an unusual goal. I want to have a website that, six days a week, displays a robust CMS website with several pages. One day a week, I want it to show a single, static html page across the whole domain. So, how do I best do this? Should I:

A) Replace and rename the CMS's index.php with my own php snippet that runs an if statement based on weekday and then loads either the CMS or the static 'index' page? The problems I can see with this is that it might cause an infinitesimal slowdown every time a user requests the page, and it might introduce instability into the CMS.

B) Add a cron job that actually swaps the files at set times every week? This seems like it could end up getting corrupted if I'm doing a file swap every week on a timer.

C) Add a cron job that edits an .htaccess file to swap references to the pages on a timer? This seems like a good solution, but I don't know how secure it is.

D) Something completely different?

Note: If it matters, the CMS is Americommerce.

Comment: Can you provide more information about your stack?

Comment: Other options: Make 2 directories, and create a symlink to your normal site, poin the document root to that symlink, remove & create a symlink to your normal site with a cronjob. But easiest: Use a `RewriteCond %{TIME_WDAY}` in your .htacess with mod_rewrite, no changing of files necessary, ever.

Comment: @ElliotFehr I'll have to check. I've never had hosting from Americommerce before. I imagine that it's a modified *AMP server, but now that I look closer, I think I'll have to get permission to implement any changes. Could you answer as if it were an up-to-date LAMP?

Comment: @Wrikken Now that looks like the best answer of all. I had no idea that .htaccess could trigger on time of day... Out of curiosity does it read server time or the local time of the request?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it in index.php.

Essentially:

```
if(date( "w" ) == 0) { // 0 = Sunday, 6 = Saturday
    require('path/to/your/static/php/file.php');
    // or file_get_contents()
} else {
    // do the normal index.php stuff
}
```

[date("w")](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) gets you the numeric day of the week, 0 being Sunday and 6 being Saturday. Then, depending on what you want to do, pull in your static file/content.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$indexFile = "index.php";
$path = "";

if (date("w") == 0) {
 $path = "sunday/"; 
}

require($path . $indexFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an include file which is included at the top of all your .php pages (before any html is printed), or you could place this in your index.php file.

You can do (essentially what the others are doing)

```
if( date("w") == 0 )
{
   header('Location: /static-file.php');
   die( );
}
```

The advantage to redirecting instead of including is that if the user tries reloading or refreshing the page they will instantly be served the static page, instead of the real website.

If you wanted to stop users going to that page (by accident) on any other day.. you could apply the same logic at the top of that static file.

```
if( date("w") != 0 )
{
   header('Location: /');
   die( );
}
```

If you didn't want to redirect, you could include the file, but I would not suggest wrapping the whole site in an if/else statement.. simply including the file and executing `die()` would be fine:

```
if( date("w") == 0 )
{
   include( 'static-file.php' );
   die( );
}
```

I would strongly advise against running a cronjob to handle something like this - as you've already pointed out there is a chance for corruption - and this is something you would have to actively check to make sure the site loads the next day. With a very simple piece of PHP, once you've tested it that first time, you know it will work flawlessly - as there is nothing complicated going on with that dow if statement.

Cronning the .htaccess file is again a headache waiting to happen.

Simplest option is to just run that piece of PHP before any CMS stuff goes on, so before any connection to the DB etc, that way you are not wasting any resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Apache's Rewrite Engine to serve different content based on time.

Make your normal (CMS) start page index.php and your static index_static.html, then add this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{TIME_WDAY} =7
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ index_static.html [L]
```